# How to get started with socket.io?

Tags: macos, node.js, socket.io

Installed Node.js and socketio io (using npm). Node `Hello World` works.

Created app.js with the following line:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
```

node `node app.js` throws exception:

```
io_test.js:1
ts, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var io = require('socket.io')();
                                                                       ^
TypeError: object is not a function
```

How to fix?

OSX 10.7.5. Node.js 0.8.18.

Answer (score 7):

Replace that line with

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
```

Basically, if you read the error description, the require('socket.io') is returning an object, not a function that you can call. If you look at the example code on the socket.io website, you can see that you can call listen() on the object returned. So, you could also write it like this:

```
var sockio = require('socket.io')
var io = sockio.listen(8080)
```